# awk update timestamp on duplicate data

Tags: linux, bash, awk, centos, tail

Given a command line as follows,

```
tail -f /var/log/somelog.log | awk '$2>100 {if (!($1 in a)) print $1, strftime ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); a[$1]=1; system("")}' > /var/log/filtered.log
```

This command takes the somelog.log file and in realtime outputs $1 only if $2 is greater than 100 and $1 doesn't already exist in the file and adds a timestamp.

What I want it to do is, update the timestamp everytime the duplicate data comes in.

Manually running a command like this produces the desired result

```
awk -v s="output from above command here" '/^"first field from above command"/{f=1;$0=s}7;END{if(!f)print s}' /var/log/filtered.log
```

For example, inputting s=111111 04-25-2014 01:00:00 and ^111111 causes "111111 04-25-2014 01:00:00" to be added to the file since it isn't there.

Inputting s=111111 04-25-2014 02:00:00 and ^111111 causes "111111 04-25-2014 01:00:00" to get overwrote with 111111 04-25-2014 02:00:00 which is the desired result

But..**how do I combine the two commands?** I've tried a test of the following which doesn't work

```
tail -f /something.log | awk -v s=$0 '/^$1/{f=1;$0=s}7;END{if(!f)print s}'
```

Edit: Clarification

Given the following input, rolling into a log file [not in file].

```
1111111 3490349 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 01:00:00am]
2103322 424 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 02:00:00am]
1323233 233444 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 03:00:00am]
1111111 2212223 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 04:00:00am]
```

I want in the output file if column b > 100000, number, newest timestamp

```
1323233 04-24-2014 03:00:00
1111111 04-24-2014 04:00:00
```

Thanks

Comment: `$0` at the shell level and `$0` at the awk level are two *very* different things. Also, are you wanting awk to rewrite existing lines in the output file when new duplicate lines come in? Because you can't do that in a streaming fashion.

Comment: Yes, overwrite as they come in. I'm open to doing it some other way if need be. A post script or something running every minute

Comment: I've re-read it multiple times but CANNOT figure out what it is you're trying to do. Why are you calling `system("")`? What is `s` intended to be? What 2 commands are you referring to in `how do I combine the two commands?`? What were you hoping `awk -v s=$0 '/^$1/...` would do? please update your question to make it much clearer including formatting sample input and output properly and removing redundant/unnecessary information.

Comment: The top 2 commands. Calling system("") to flush the buffer. I could use flush("") but system("") appears to work

Comment: s in the 2nd command is a number, followed by a timestamp

Comment: awk operates on a stream and outputs a stream it *cannot* by definition modify a previous entry in the file. If you want to do that you are going to need an external process for that (which will cause you problems if this awk command is running at the same time).

Comment: Please post some SMALL sample input (i.e. a few lines of `/var/log/somelog.log`, including some examples of lines you want modified and some you don't) and the final output you want as I think that would help a lot.

Comment: ok, I'll have to stop tail/awk, run an external command (a sort and awk?) and then start the awk back up. That is ok with me, trying to figure out the sort/awk now

Comment: Please focus first on defining the problem. The solutions you are suggesting are just muddying the waters.

Comment: Ed - edited with example

Comment: Looks like `tac /somelogfile.log | awk '!x[$1]++'` works for post processing it

Answer (score 1):

You don't show where the date came from in your output as it's not present in your input, so I'm ignoring that but this should get you very close to what you need:

```
$ cat file
1111111 3490349 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 01:00:00am]
2103322 424 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 02:00:00am]
1323233 233444 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 03:00:00am]
1111111 2212223 daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [added 04:00:00am]

$ awk '
$2>100000 {
    keys[$1]
    sub(/.m\]/,"")
    time[$1]=$NF
}
END {
    for (key in keys)
        print key, time[key]
}
' file
1111111 04:00:00
1323233 03:00:00
```